# Is this H bridge circuit viable

Tags: transistors, dc-motor, schematics, h-bridge, mosfet-driver

I am trying to create an H bridge circuit from scratch to control a 2 wire DC permanent magnet motor. I have done research online, but I haven't had any formal schooling in electronics, so please be patient and kindly bring any noticeable problems with the circuit to my attention. Is there anything that would make this circuit better? Are the diodes set up properly to protect this circuit from motor voltage spikes?[image: schematic]

J2 and J3 are screw terminals where I would connect V+, GND, and the two motor wires. J2 is GND and V+ and J3 is motor output. Input A and B would ideally be controlled by a +5v logic level coming from a microcontroller output.

UPDATE: 
Thanks everyone for the constructive comments they are really helping.

Can I fix the shoot through problem by making one a depletion and one an enhancement type FET? 
Also,

> gate capacitances and 10 k pull-up resistor will cause the collectro
>   voltage to take potentially micro seconds to rise back to the positive
>   rail

can I fix this by using a smaller resistor such as 2k ohm and a diode such as this?

[image: Diode mosfet drain]

Comment: You mean Output, right?

Comment: The MOSFET selection is critical as shoot-thru shorting of the supply is possible during switching.  Ideally the Vgs threshold is >=1/2  V+ on all parts and RdsOn is much lower than the motor coil DCR? A push-pull driver is faster than R pullup on collector turn off.  The diodes don't prevent turn off spikes , rather it isolates the spikes from the FETS

Comment: the gatedrives are going to provide issue w.r.t. switching times. Hi->Low is ok... but Lo->High could be slow. Why have you got those zeners there?  This is going to cause freewheel current issues.

Comment: @Tyler Yes Tyler, I have cleared up the phrasing a bit. Thank you for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: What motor supply voltage do you intend to use, and what are the part numbers of Q1~Q4?

Comment: @JonRB - the diodes are Schottky, not Zeners.

Comment: @DwayneReid I was hoping they were not and it was more of a bad symbol choice. They will block the freewheel path...

Comment: @BruceAbbott I will be driving a 24v motor. The FETs are [IRF9630](http://www.vishay.com/docs/91084/sihf9630.pdf)(p channel) and [IRF630](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf630npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355e7ae3819e6) (n channel)

Comment: @JonRB I read that you are supposed to have diodes for inductive loads when driving with a transistor or else it can supply a few hundred volts to the FET and kill it. Am I using the wrong type of diodes for this application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one major problem with your H-Bridge and two possible issues depending on the mode of operation

### Lack of bulk capacitance

There doesn't appear to be any large value capacitors near the H-bridge. Now maybe J2 is right up close to relatively large capacitor, likewise the H-Bridge may only operate as a dumb fwd and rev control with no PWM.

if however you plan to send any form of modulation then the lack of bulk capacitance will start to have an affect on operation. ringing close to the H-Bridge, potentially overvoltage, poor transient response.

### Gatedrive type

The complete circuit uses a BJT to pull the gates of a LEG to 0V and a 10k to pull it high.

This means the BJT can pull the GATES low (Ntype going OFF, Ptype going ON) very fast but the 10k is needed to pull the gates HIGH (Ntype going ON, Ptype going OFF)

If you plan to PWM the gates & if the the inverter was of any real power you would want to switch the FET's fast enough to minimise switching losses but slow enough to mitigate any ringing & shoot-through mitigated via deadtime.

The alternative, especially when you are using a complementary pair you aim to have slow TURN-ON and fast TURN-OFF for each switch. With the presented drive topology when when **INPUT_A** or **INPUT_B** transitions **LOW** to **HIGH** you might be ok as the Ntype turns off FAST and the Ptype turns on "fast".  However... for a **HIGH** to **LOW** transition on **INPUT_A** or **INPUT_B** the NTYPE will turn ON slowly and hte PTYPE will turn OFF slowly ... depending on the gate capacitance and the gate threshold w.r.t. the DCLink voltage you could experience a soft shoot-through for this transition

Again this might not be an issue if you do not plan to PWM at any reasonable frequency.

The main problem however...

### H-Bridge Topology.

You are right H-Bridges & inductive loads need a freewheel path and you have that with the four FET via the intrisic diode. You however have added 4 additional diodes and they will fail the moment you attempt a H-bridge state transition.

The classic H-BRidge.

[image]

There are five LEGAL states in a H-bridge there are then two ILLEGAL & four that do nothing.

The LEGAL states are:

1. All switches OFF - any current would freewheel by the supply & decay
2. 1 & 2 ON - positive current can build up in the load
3. 3 & 4 ON - negative current can build up in the load
4. 1 & 3 ON - zero volt loop that minimises load current decay OR shorts winding.
5. 2 & 4 ON - zero volt loop that minimises load current decay OR shorts windings.

[image]

Due to your gatedrive Topology State1 is only reachable when the power is off. With no INPUT_A,B the gatedrive force the bridge to State5 (bottom FET's ON)

Now consider your topology.

[image]

Now consider transitioning from State2 --> State5 because of loss of control or trying to use the zero volt state: Because the upper FET's are open the current wants to commutate via the lower diodes BUT the additional diodes are now blocking the freewheel path. The inductor only cares about satifying \$V = L\frac{\Delta i}{\Delta t}\$ & with this topology you are attempting to instantaneously STOP the current flow and thus the voltage will increase to maintain the current flow until those additional diodes avalanche & be destroyed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jon, it is very thorough and informative. I see what you mean about the diodes I added being a problem. If I'm understanding this correctly, the diodes integrated into the FETs should usually be able to handle the current until it is dissipated naturally. I'm sure this would depend much on the FET though. @Tony **_"A push-pull driver is faster than R pullup on collector turn off"_** I will try to re-design the circuit using these suggestions and add another transistor instead of the pull-up resistor and see how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Unlikely that it is suitable: -

- Both Q1 and Q2 can be on at the same time (this is called shoot through) and is to be generally avoided. The transistor that feeds them may be only lightly driven and operate linearly producing a collector voltage that is mid rail and bang, there's the main issue. Also, even if activating that transistor correctly, when it turns off, the gate capacitances and 10 k pull-up resistor will cause the collectro voltage to take potentially micro seconds to rise back to the positive rail and shoot-through will occur.
- Ditto Q3 and Q4
- D1, D2, D3 and D4 are superfluous to the protection unless you are trying to get rid of the stored energy in the motor very quickly - the internal diodes in each mosfet will dump excess energy into the power rail BUT for this to work adequately you need a reservoir capacitor across the rails close to the H bridge.
- You might find that when the power rails are too low, the MOSFETs don't turn on properly and burn - use an UVLO system (under voltage lock-out to disable the MOSFETs from being driven when the supply is too low).
- If too high a supply is given, the MOSFET gate breakdown voltages may be exceeded. Now I have no idea if this is possible but you asked!

Comment: D1-D4 won't provide freewheel.  they block

Comment: @JonRB yeah they block for the first 20V then they breakdown (thus removing inductive stored energy much quicker than if they were short circuits). I was trying to be kind to the OP (it happens now and then)!

Comment: well that is one way to look at it :) have a +1